# Avoid a label showing twice when i click a button twice in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a math quiz and I'm trying to do error handling. I want `self.wrongnum.destroy()` to be called only when it has previously displayed the label `wrongnum` . What's happening right now is that if i click a button twice (which will display the label `wrongnum` if there's something wrong with the value the user has inputted), the label will also display on top of one another, but only 1 label is destroyed. What can i do to avoid 2 of the same label ever appearing? or how can i destroy both?

Below is my code, if there's anything else that's wrong with the way I made it, please tell me as well. thanks

```
    def q2(self, master):
        randomiser()
        global answer
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=200, pady=200)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.user_choice = StringVar()
        self.user_choice.set("")
        self.q = Label(self.frame, text="What is {} x {} ?".format(x, y))
        self.q.grid(row=0)
        self.ans = Entry(self.frame, width=50, textvariable=self.user_choice)
        self.ans.grid(row=1)
        answer = x*y
        self.sub = Button(self.frame, text="submit", command=lambda:[self.check(), randomiser()])
        self.sub.grid(row=3)

    def check(self):
        try:
            if self.user_choice == None:
                self.wrongnum = Label(self.frame, text="Please enter a number")
                self.wrongnum.grid(row=5)
                self.necs()
            else:
                self.correct()
        except ValueError:
            self.wrongnum = Label(self.frame, text="Please enter a number")
            self.wrongnum.grid(row=5)

    def correct(self):
        global p
        if int(self.user_choice.get()) == answer:
            cor = Label(self.frame,text="Correct!")
            cor.grid(row=5, pady=20)
            p += 1
            self.sub.destroy()
            self.wrongnum.destroy() 
            nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", command=self.necs)
            nex.grid(row=4)
        else:
            inc = Label(self.frame,text="incorrect, the correct answer is {}".format(answer))
            inc.grid(row=5, pady=20)
            self.sub.destroy()
            nex = Button(self.frame, text="Next", command=self.necs)
            nex.grid(row=4)
```

Comment: Create the label in `q2` with text of empty string and in the `check` callback just change the label text.

Comment: Mark Lin, you want something like this: [Maths Quiz](https://repl.it/repls/SuburbanMushyDiscussion#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a button when it is pressed:

button["state"] = DISABLED

For example:

```
def button_pressed:
    button["state"] = DISABLED
```

Then to enable it,

```
button["state"] = ENABLED
```